# How to clean up the pixellated edges in this image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, raster

[image: str8vapor]

The edges in the above image are very pixelized and I need to smoothen them out.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Please provide us with a bit more information about how this image was made. Without that, it's guessing what would be a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try recreating  the whole image? it's much easier.
The font used up there is Arial Black (extra bold).

[image]

You can then use strokes and shapes to do the rest.

Hope that's useful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know your way with Photoshop I'm with Jasmine on this. It should be quite easy to recreate that.

But on the other hand if you like to try a different kind of approach, here goes:

I would use Pen Tool to trace work path around rasterized areas,

[image: Picture of work path added]

select the path and fill it with black on a new layer

[image: Picture of black fill layer added]

and then use a white brush to paint over the undesired pixels.

[image: Picture of white fill layer added]

Not the most sophisticated solution, but could also work.

-M